# adding multiple div in JS using createElemnt

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var div4=document.getElementById('div4'); // get the div element
var div2=document.getElementById('div2'); // create a new div
for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    var newDiv=document.createElement("div"); //create a new div
    var newDiv2=document.createElement("div") //create a new div
    newDiv.innerHTML=array[index];
    newDiv.draggable = true;
    newDiv.id = 'record-2-'+index;
    newDiv.className = 'record';
    newDiv2.className = 'record';
    newDiv2.id = 'record-4-'+index;
    newDiv2.draggable = true;
    newDiv2.innerHTML=array[index];
    div4.appendChild(newDiv); // append to div
    div2.appendChild(newDiv2); // append to div
    newDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
    newDiv2.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
}
```

How I can achive same functionality without having two separate variable **newDiv, newDiv2**.

Comment: what is you final goal ?

Comment: This is quite unclear right know, please elaborate.

Comment: Use a function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the div and add that by using `cloneNode()`, so you are adding two separate divs, not the one same one.

```
var div4=document.getElementById('div4'); // get the div element
var div2=document.getElementById('div2'); // create a new div
for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    var newDiv=document.createElement("div"); //create a new div
    newDiv.innerHTML=array[index];
    newDiv.draggable = true;
    newDiv.id = 'record-2-'+index;
    newDiv.className = 'record';

    div4.appendChild(newDiv); // append to div
    newDiv = newDiv.cloneNode(false); // clone the div
    newDiv.id = 'record-4-'+index; // change its id property
    div2.appendChild(newDiv); // append to div
    newDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
    newDiv2.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function wich return or adds the div to a passed div:

```js
//Required..
function handleDragStart(){};

//Created and append divs
function addDivTo(div, html, id){
    //appendChild() returns the input
    var newDiv = div.appendChild(document.createElement("div")); //create a new div
    newDiv.id = id;
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    newDiv.draggable = true;
    newDiv.className = 'record';
    newDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart)
  }

//Some array used below
var array = ['123', '456', '789', 'cucubau'];

var div4 = document.getElementById('div4'); // get the div element
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2'); // create a new div

for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  addDivTo(div4, array[index], 'record4-' + index);
  addDivTo(div2, array[index], 'record2-' + index)
}
```

```html
<div id = 'div4'></div>
<div id = 'div2'></div>
```